# Can I use the same animations on different rigs?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones, workflow

So for the sake of time, I was hoping there'd be a way for me to get skeletons to replicate each other. Like if I have a mesh/skeleton/face rig of Mario and a mesh/skeleton/face rig of Sonic (different size and shape of each other) and I want them to dance in sync and I've already animated Mario, is there a way for me to "copy and paste" or "drag and drop" his movements onto the Sonic rig?

Comment: Animations are groups of keyframes stored in *Actions*. Multiple armatures (skeletons) can indeed share an action. However the rig would have to be specifically designed to use the same keyframes value for bones with different proportions.